# Does CardView's elevation depends upon the position on the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have more than 3 `CardView` displayed on a screen as an item of a `RecyclerView`.

I have realized recently that the elevation of the `CardView` is different for a different card or the position of the card view on the screen.

You can see it in the picture attached to this question:

[image: i have 3 cards and to distinguish I add different colors to them]

- **Blue** `CardView` - the top shadow of the card has a clear darkgrey line and the bottom line has less shadow compared to others.
- **Yellow** `CardView` - the top shadow of the card has a less clear grey line and the bottom line has dark shadow compared to others.
- **Red** `CardView` - the top shadow of the card has a negligible grey line as compared to others.

Is it normal or am I doing something wrong?

The `CardView` layout is same for all the three as they are in `RecyclerView`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff"
            app:cardElevation="1dp"/>
```

Comment: Is is perfectly normal, every view does this. It should "bring perspective" into ui. Views positioned higher on the screen have smaller elevation and views positioned lower on the screen have bigger elevation.

Comment: What if I want the same elevation at all positions?? Will that be possible??

Comment: I am unsure. It may be possible, if you get position of the view on screen and calculate it's elevation and set it programmatically using View.setElevation(). But this will depend on device metrics and could be very clumsy if views change their position on the screen.